# Is there a way to load Google Fonts into Devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I know I can import the font I would like to use into the CSS file with the Devtools open. It just seems like a no-brainer for Google to have their massive Fonts library linked to Devtools. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is too old, but this might help others. Type in console following code, then you can use it in Element>styles

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.body.prepend(link);
```

Answer (score 3):

Select an element in **Elements** panel > **DOM Tree** and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit the `<head`> tag of your HTML. From there, just add the `<link>` tag to your HTML. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to save your changes.

[image: editing HTML]

In the **Network** panel you'll see a request for the font file.

[image: network request for font file]